# Swift Custom Callout for MKMapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I am implementing custom callout view for mapview. I am getting this output

[image]

For annotation view I am using

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

     let reuseId = "mapPin"
   var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? CustomCalloutView
    if anView == nil {
    anView=CustomCalloutView(annotation: annotation,reuseIdentifier:reuseId)
        anView!.image = UIImage(named:"mappin.png")
        let button : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView=button
     //anView!.addSubview(viewC)
    mapViewControl.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
```

and to popup callout view

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!){
    var viewC:UIView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    viewC.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

   view.addSubview(viewC)
    viewC.center = CGPointMake(viewC.bounds.size.width*0.1, -viewC.bounds.size.height*0.5)


}
```

Comment: Why there is downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe it's because you have not stated what the problem is exactly.  By the way: In viewForAnnotation, why are you calling addAnnotation -- that doesn't make sense.  Also, instead of addTarget for the rightCalloutAccessoryView, use the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method.

Comment: Next time be more direct with your question. But this is actually a pretty good implementation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution. Its very small change. In viewForAnnotation hide the basic callout as follow,

```
anView!.canShowCallout = false
```